jupyter server --generate-config Command Not working
I recently deleted and reinstalled /opt/anaconda3 on my mac (running macOS Monterey, v.12.7.2.)
When I run "jupyter server --generate-config" I get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/4.1.6_1/libexec/bin/jupyter-server", line 5, in 
from jupyter_server.serverapp import main
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_server/serverapp.py", line 30, in 
import jupyter_client
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_client/init.py", line 3, in 
from .asynchronous import AsyncKernelClient
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_client/asynchronous/init.py", line 1, in 
from .client import AsyncKernelClient  # noqa
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_client/asynchronous/client.py", line 8, in 
import zmq.asyncio
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/zmq/init.py", line 103, in 
from zmq import backend
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/zmq/backend/init.py", line 31, in 
raise original_error from None
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/zmq/backend/init.py", line 26, in 
_ns = select_backend(first)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/zmq/backend/select.py", line 31, in select_backend
mod = import_module(name)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/importlib/init.py", line 90, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/init.py", line 6, in 
from . import (
ImportError: cannot import name '_device' from partially initialized module 'zmq.backend.cython' (most likely due to a circular import) (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/init.py)
Please help,
Jonathan
I haven't tried any additional steps, because I don't know what to try.

In your error, I see "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/importlib/init.py and "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/init.py",You've messed up your install by mixing and matching installation methods it seems. It should all be Anaconda it is referencing because you seem to have installed the Anaconda Distribution and thus  opted at that time to make that your primary package distribution system and you should stick with only using Anaconda/conda for installations. Unless there's no conda recipe, and ...

 then only in those cases can you use pip. Keeping in mind the environments then won't be robust and portable. (Plus I see /usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/4.1.6_1/libexec/bin/jupyter-server. Yikes. Severely messed up considering everything should be using Anaconda.) So it looks like you need to clean up that other stuff, if indeed you know you installed it. (This might help.) Then you may still need to uninstall and reinstall Anaconda to fully register everything is linked to that. Obviously, ...

 though you want to do this delicately so you don't make matters worse. Do you know what the Cellar is? Is that an app? Yours looks different than where I referred you. Are you using the Anaconda navigator to launch things and running that jupyter server --generate-config in there? If not, you should be doing that and maye things aren't as messed up as it looks form that traceback.

Wayne: "/usr/local/Cellar/" contains software installed by Homebrew.

RESOLVED -- conflicting installations of Python.

If something specific sorted it out, you could expand on that.

Wayne: You were right it was the conflict between /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/importlib/init.py' and /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/init.py`. I got rid of the former, and now everything works.
